# Using SUMIFS with Indirect

Tags: excel

The values are found in another workbook based on today's date
So I tried the following formula

`SUMIFS(INDIRECT (TEXT(TODAY()-1,"dd-mmm-yyyy")&" DSR Updates TL.xlsb!Table1[SALES_QTY]"), INDIRECT (TEXT(TODAY ()-1,"dd-mmm-yyyy")&" DSR Updates TL.xlsb!Table1[Tagging]"),D6)`

But `#REF!` is the response. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Without using indirect, this is the formula

`SUMIFS('22-Jan-2020 DSR Updates TL.xlsb'!Table1[SALES_QTY],'22-Jan-2020 DSR Updates TL.xlsb'!Table1[Tagging],D6)`

And this returns the value I need

Comment: Does the name of workbook `DSR Updates TL.xlsb` really start with a space?

Comment: Yes, for example, the name of the workbook today is ```22-Jan-2020 DSR Updates TL"```

Comment: The INDIRECT function allows you to specify a cell address as text, like `=INDIRECT("A3")` which is the same as `=A3`. But `=INDIRECT(A3)` would require A3 to contain a valid address as text. So, if A3 contains the text string *"Sheet1!B17"* then `=INDIRECT(A3)` would be paramount to `=Sheet1!B17`. By changing the text in A3, perhaps with the help of a drop-down, the formula would return the value of a different cell. It doesn't appear as if your INDIRECT functions return valid cell addresses. Make your formula work with direct addressing first.

Comment: What's "Indirect" about constructing a worksheet name using a variable? Technically, there are no tables in a workbook. Tables are in Worksheets. If the worksheet name contains spaces it must be surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: ```SUMIFS(TEXT(TODAY()-1,"dd-mmm-yyyy")&" DSR Updates TL.xlsb"!Table1[SALES_QTY],TEXT(TODAY ()-1,"dd-mmm-yyyy")&" DSR Updates TL.xlsb"!Table1[Tagging],D6)``` Returns an error with the formula itself

Comment: Indeed, all that's wrong with your formula is the missing sheet and the missing single quotes. I'll post an answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the formula that should work. It's based on the assumption that your table is on `Sheet1`. I was unable to omit the sheet name from the syntax. Please correct the name if it's different.

```
=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'["&TEXT(TODAY()-1,"dd-mmm-yyyy")&" DSR Updates TL.xlsb]Sheet1'!Table1[Sales_Qty]"),INDIRECT("'["&TEXT(TODAY()-1,"dd-mmm-yyyy")&" DSR Updates TL.xlsb]Sheet1'!Table1[Tagging]"),D6)
```

Of course, this formula is untested. Here is the gist of its development that *was* tested, alas, with a different file name.

[A1] =TEXT(TODAY()-1,"dd-mmm-yyyy")&" DSR Updates TL.xlsb"
[A2 =] Sheet1
[A3 =] Table1[Tagging]

The formula below returns the sum of the addressed column.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'["&A1&"]"&A2&"'!"&A3))
```

Comment: I changed the sheet name, but still there's an error with the formula. When I press enter, I get an error and the chunk ```TL.xlsb"]Sellout``` is highlited

Comment: Yes. That was an error in setting the quote marks when I assembled the formula. I have corrected it in my answer above. Sorry about that. Please try again.

Comment: It works now! Thanks. And just to be clear, my problem with ```[``` and ```'```, right?

Comment: Yes and no. It's the basic syntax. a) Workbook **and** worksheet must be provided. b) The combination of the two must follow the applicable syntax, i.e. workbook in square brackets, workbook + worksheet between single quotes, followed by an exclamation point. I think the template, provided above, is helpful: `=SUM(INDIRECT("'["&A1&"]"&A2&"'!"&A3))`